# How to test REST client without REST server(Controller)

Tags: python-3.x, rest, go

There are 2 parts for a REST API.

1. Client - One that calls the rest API by setting header and passing the payload.
2. Server - One that swallows the rest request and does carryout business logic.
   If the API design is agreed upon, we should be able to coded client & server parallelly.

REST ***Server changes can be tested by REST client*** tools like postman, swagger, Advanced REST client etc

**How do i test REST client changes** ? say i want to demo and show the header, URL, REST method like PUT/POST along with the json payload sent as request body
Example: output should show

- http://localhost:11111/schemas/employee
- PUT
- Content-Type : application/custom.schema+json
- Accept : application/json

I tried the link https://github.com/nickjj/webserver but it does not work for put. it only works for get and post

I am attaching the sample **GO lang** code if needed

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var testFile, _ = filepath.Abs("/testSchema.json")
var schemaURL = "http://localhost:11111/schemas/employee"

func manageSchema(schemaEndpoint string) error {
    pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    employeeData, _ := os.ReadFile(pwd + testFile)
    fmt.Println(string(employeeData))
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, schemaEndpoint, bytes.NewBuffer(employeeData))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/custom.schema+json")
    request.Header.Set("accept", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("PUT example endpoint : ", schemaEndpoint)
        fmt.Print(err)
        return err
    }
    defer func(Body io.ReadCloser) {
        err := Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Closing request body", err)
        }
    }(response.Body)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    manageSchema(schemaURL)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for . https://pipedream.com/requestbin  is a solution if you want to check if your requestes are being made as how you would expect it to be made

Comment: Or you could explore https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest as well.